# Can you Wish for a Deck of Many Things?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, wish

My Pathfinder character was recently granted a [Wish](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/wish.html) spell. I *really* want a [Deck of Many Things](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/artifacts/minor-artifacts/deck-of-many-things). Rules as written, can I use the Wish to get a Deck of Many things? Preferably, without invoking the "You may try to use a wish to produce greater effects than these, but doing so is dangerous" clause?

Comment: The best and worst thing you can do to a character that wishes for something is to give it to them.

Comment: *Especially* true in this case, I'd say. The things should really be named 'Deck of Random Campaign Derailment and Character Unplayability Opportunities'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since the Deck is a Minor Artefact without a listed price, the Wish spell cannot create one. The only reasonable way to resolve the spell is if it summons an existing Deck to you, which means that its old owner now is missing a Deck of Many Things.

Which probably puts you in "doing so is dangerous" territory, depending on who the old owner of the Deck was (which is up to your DM)